# The "loss of connectivity" modal in mobile chat is intrusive

Tags: feature-request, bug, chat, usability

When connectivity is lost using the mobile chat, a modal box politely indicates this. The issue is, while the box is dismiss-able, it will immediately reappear if connectivity has not been reestablished.

This is problematic when I *know* I have no connection (*elevator, basement, bomb-shelter*) but intend on reading the conversation up to the point of connection loss, as the modal box is quite intrusive.

I'm proposing a fix to temporarily disable connectivity notifications that could be reset when connectivity has been reestablished.

Comment: A workaround I frequently use: If you dismiss it and then scroll back up really fast it appears out of the way of the bit you've probably already read.

Comment: @Flexo That's the workaround I use too; despite the fun in the test of dexterity, I think we can do without the mini-game ;)